# To fit Linear regression Model with and without intercept in python

Tags: linear-regression, statsmodels

I need to fit Linear regression Model 1 : `y = β1x1 + ε` and Model 2: `y = β0 + β1x1 + ε`, to the data x1 = ([0,1,2,3,4])
y = ([1,2,3,2,1]). My objective is to find
coefficients, squared error loss, the absolute error loss, and the L1.5 loss for both model.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import numpy as np

x1 = ([0,1,2,3,4])
y = ([1,2,3,2,1])
```

would you please show me some way to get these?

Comment: See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#ordinary-least-squares, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-ols-py

Answer (score 1):

This first method doesn't use the formula api.

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
y = np.array([1,2,3,2,1])
x1 = x1[:, None] # Transform into a (5,1) atrray

res = sm.OLS(y,x1).fit()

print(res.summary())
```

If you want to use the formula interface, you need to build a `DataFrame`, and then the regression is `"y ~ x1"` (if you want a constant you need to include `+1` on the right-hand-side of the formula.

```py
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd

x1 = [0,1,2,3,4]
y = [1,2,3,2,1]
data = pd.DataFrame({"y":y,"x1":x1})
res = smf.ols("y ~ x1", data).fit()
print(res.summary())
```

Either produce

```
                            OLS Regression Results
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.000
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                 -0.333
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                 4.758e-16
Date:                Wed, 17 Mar 2021   Prob (F-statistic):               1.00
Time:                        22:11:40   Log-Likelihood:                -5.6451
No. Observations:                   5   AIC:                             15.29
Df Residuals:                       3   BIC:                             14.51
Df Model:                           1
Covariance Type:            nonrobust
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept      1.8000      0.748      2.405      0.095      -0.582       4.182
x1                  0      0.306          0      1.000      -0.972       0.972
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                          nan   Durbin-Watson:                   1.429
Prob(Omnibus):                    nan   Jarque-Bera (JB):                0.375
Skew:                           0.344   Prob(JB):                        0.829
Kurtosis:                       1.847   Cond. No.                         4.74
==============================================================================

Notes:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
```

to include an intercept in the non-formula API, you can simply use

```
res_constant = sm.OLS(y, sm.add_constant(x1).fit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sklearn's LinearRegression.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression)

For the one without intercept (wanting to fit the model to intercept at origin), simply set the parameter `fit_intercept = False`